# Concatenate onto Next Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have some SQL that does some manipulation to the data i.e. filling in empty columns.

```
SELECT *,
    ModifiedLineData = CASE
        WHEN Column2 = '' AND LineData NOT LIKE ',,,0,,,,0'
            THEN CONCAT(STUFF(LineData, CHARINDEX(',', LineData, CHARINDEX(',', LineData) + 1), 0, '"No PO Number"'), ',""')
        ELSE CONCAT(LineData, ',""')
    END
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        Column2 = CONVERT(XML, '<s>' + REPLACE((SELECT ISNULL(LineData, '') FOR XML PATH('')), ',', '</s><s>') + '</s>').value('/s[2]', 'varchar(100)')
    FROM [dbo].[Temp_Raw_Data]
    WHERE LineData NOT LIKE ',,,0,,,,0'
) AS Subquery
```

Now lets say this returns

| FileName | LineNumber | LineData | Column2 | ModifiedLineData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | 4 | 1232,,"product-1", 1,0 |  | 1232,NA,"product-1", 1,0 |
| file2 | 7 | "failed" | NULL | "failed" |
| file3 | 8 | 1235,,"product-2", 1,0 |  | 1235,NA,"product-2", 1,0 |

How can I modify this query so that if Column2 is NULL then it would concatenate the LineData onto the next row (ModifiedLineData) else just concatenate a ,"" and then remove that NULL result (if possible else it doesnt matter) so that my result would look like:

| FileName | LineNumber | LineData | Column2 | ModifiedLineData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | 4 | 1232,,"product-1", 1,0 |  | 1232,NA,"product-1", 1,0,"" |
| file3 | 8 | 1235,,"product-2", 1,0 |  | 1235,NA,"product-2", 1,0,"failed" |

I tried playing around with LEAD() but couldn't get it how i wanted.

Note: Two null rows are not possible to be together. This is due to the nature of the data. The next row should simply be the next available row when selecting all rows as they are imported one by 1.

Updated Query that isn't concatenating:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT FileName, LineNumber, LineData, Column2, 
               CASE WHEN LAG(Column2) OVER(ORDER BY LineNumber) IS NULL
                    THEN CONCAT_WS(', ',
                                ModifiedLineData, 
                                LAG(ModifiedLineData) OVER(ORDER BY LineNumber))
                    ELSE ModifiedLineData
               END AS ModifiedLineData
        FROM (
        SELECT *,
            ModifiedLineData = CASE
                WHEN Column2 = '' AND LineData NOT LIKE ',,,0,,,,0'
                    THEN CONCAT(STUFF(LineData, CHARINDEX(',', LineData, CHARINDEX(',', LineData) + 1), 0, '"No PO Number"'), '')
                ELSE CONCAT(LineData, '')
            END
        FROM (
            SELECT *,
                Column2 = CONVERT(XML, '<s>' + REPLACE((SELECT ISNULL(LineData, '') FOR XML PATH('')), ',', '</s><s>') + '</s>').value('/s[2]', 'varchar(100)')
            FROM [backstreet_WMS_Optimizer].[dbo].[Temp_GoodsIn_Raw_Data]
            WHERE LineData NOT LIKE ',,,0,,,,0'
        ) AS Subquery
    ) AS cte
) AS Subquery
WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL
order by FileName, LineNumber
```

Comment: What happens if you have two `NULL` rows together? And how do you define "next row", what ordering?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @Charlieface Two null rows are not possible to be together. This is due to the nature of the data. The next row should simply be the next available row when selecting all rows as they are imported one by 1.

Comment: There is no inherent ordering in SQL. Unless you have an `ORDER BY` the rows can be in any order. Perhaps you want `ORDER BY LineNumber` or `ORDER BY FileName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you can't have consecutive NULL values, using `LEAD`/`LAG` should be suitable for this task. Without knowledge of your original data, we can work on your query and add on top two subqueries, last of which is optional:

- the inner adds the information needed to the record successive to "*Column2=NULL*" records
- the outer removes records having those null values

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT FileName, LineNumber, LineData, Column2, 
               CASE WHEN LAG(Column2) OVER(ORDER BY LineNumber) IS NULL
                    THEN CONCAT_WS(', ',
                                ModifiedLineData, 
                                LAG(ModifiedLineData) OVER(ORDER BY LineNumber))
                    ELSE ModifiedLineData
               END AS ModifiedLineData
        FROM <your query>) cte
WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL
```

**Output**:

| FileName | LineNumber | LineData | Column2 | ModifiedLineData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | 4 | 1232,,"product-1", 1,0 |  | 1232,NA,"product-1", 1,0 |
| file3 | 8 | 1235,,"product-2", 1,0 |  | 1235,NA,"product-2", 1,0"failed" |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IFyccF8q).

Comment: This would work assuming Column2 and ModifiedLineData were part of the table. But as you can see from my original query they are built up based on other factors. How would I merge the two queries, both mine and yours in that manner?

Comment: Substitute `<your query>` with your query.

Comment: So I've merged the two successfully but its not concatenating onto the end. Just a note with your query it should concatenate with ,"failed" (notice the comma before concatenate)

Comment: Charlieface preceeded me on editing (thanks for that). Apart from it, if your query is working, and my solution begins from the output of your query, I can't understand why it shouldn't be working when you combine your query with this tested one...

Comment: I've updated the main post with my new code. Let me know if you spot anything wrong there?

Comment: You've used a slightly different code of yours, not the first one you posted here. Can you double-check if your new code corresponds to your previous code in terms of inputs and outputs?

Comment: Hm well i created a fiddle and it produces the result i want but in my SSMS it doesnt. https://dbfiddle.uk/FcT85oVp. Weird

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` returns?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU18-GDR) (KB5021124) - 15.0.4280.7 (X64)   Jan 23 2023 12:37:13   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )

Comment: Even in SQL Server 2019 you get the [same output](https://dbfiddle.uk/33mpTpxJ). From my side can't help you further without knowledge of your own environment. I can suggest to check for differences and backtrace to where the issues (in terms of different output) stem from.

Comment: Indeed. I'm a bit lost on this one but its getting quite late so i'll give it another shot tomorrow. Thank you i'll mark it as resolved as it technically works and an issue on my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253930/discussion-between-scuffedcoder-and-lemon).